# Amazon EMR: Using R code in Amazon EMR

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I have a very beginner question. I've just been reading through some of the documentation regarding Amazon's EMR. Before I sign up etc. I just wanted to ask about using R in it.

I have one R module that calls several other modules, and then, just before it finishes running, saves several variables as .txt files.

My rather basic question is, can I do this in Amazon's EMR? And will I be able to access the .txt output files? Finally, my R script reads in some data from Excel spreadsheets. Will it still be able to do this from the EMR if I upload the Excel files into the system?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: It's not clear how emr can be related to R script launching? Do you know what hadoop is and how map-reduce pattern works?

Comment: @alko, I only know what I've recently read. My understanding is that Hadoop and map-reduce patterns spread the computing power of several computers (i.e. maps the process to several computers) and then, at the end, aggregates the results onto one system (i.e. reduces it). Is this correct? From there, I looked at the Amazon EMR system, which seems to indicate that one can run R script using the streaming cluster process. Is this correct? Thanks alko!

Comment: "MapReduce with R on Hadoop and Amazon EMR" - http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/mapreduce-r-hadoop-amazon-emr/

Answer (score 2):

@Mike, Answers to your 3 questions below

- **Running R on EMR:** Yes you can.
  You can run R programs on EMR once you have installed R on the EMR instance. I assume that you would write MapReduce moules if you plan to use multi-instance cluster. If you program is just about a "plain" R program then you may have to just use one sizable instance. I would rather use an EC2 instance with R AMI (look for Louis Aslett).
- **Moving output files:**
  Yes you can. It is possible to transfer your program output from EMR to S3 storage bucket of your choice. You will have to add a step calling S3DistCp command to move the files. An example from my project -

  ```
  --jar /home/hadoop/lib/emr-s3distcp-1.0.jar --args '--src,hdfs:///contents,--dest,s3://<bucket-name>/'
  ```
- **Reading spreadsheets:** AFAIK, If you are able to do this on local installation of R, then you should also be able to do it on EMR. You have to ensure that the necessary packages/libraries are installed during the bootstrap process.

I am able to install squeezy-cran and rmr2 on an EMR instance with all their dependencies (RCpp, reshap2, digest, RJSONIO, functional etc.). I am still unable to call the R program as a step. I am having to use SSH session and run `R CMD` commands on the shell prompt. Being on Windows, `putty.exe` works for me.

Comment: R is preinstalled and for S3 no further measures are necessary - S3 is integrated with EMR by default.